# If I kill cheaters on my own team in CS:GO, will the match still count as a loss after they get VAC banned?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I recently attempted to play a competitive CS:GO match, and I wound up with some blatant cheaters on my team. I, along with my friend who I had queued with, tried to convince them to stop, but our attempts were unsuccessful. We wound up just teamkilling them as many times as we could to try to reduce the damage to the other team.

So, my question is this: if they get VAC banned, will this game still count as a loss for me? I am **not** asking if loosing to cheaters counts as a loss, as I'm aware that loosing to cheaters on the opposing team doesn't count after they get banned. What I'm asking is, if you get kicked for teamkilling cheaters on your own team (meaning that the round counts as a loss even if they wound up winning), and they eventually get VAC banned, will this still count as a loss for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a player is VAC banned all wins that player had are invalidated, therefore, you and everyone else on your team recover your lost mmr after he's banned. ( I've seen this happen before where someone on my team was cheating and I recovered my elo )

Also, don't kill them, since you could get reported and get overwatch banned for team killing.

The best thing you can do is report him every round.